# How do I do the infinite ammo glitch?

Tags: borderlands-2

A glitch or exploit that I often see in speed-runs somehow makes it so that weapons don't cost ammo to fire. How do they do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Wield a Vladof rocket launcher.
(2) Fire it until the next shot is a free shot (i.e. won't cost ammo).
(3) Switch away from the Vladof rocket launcher (without using the inventory menu).
(4) Before the animation of pulling out the next weapon begins, change the Vladof rocket launcher's weapon slot position (in the inventory menu). 
Thenceforth, weapons will cost one less ammo to fire until you wield the Vladof rocket launcher again. The glitch is also known as the Vladof rocket launcher glitch for the obvious reason.

I suspect that this glitch is doable with other weapons that have an identical effect. This seems to be a subset of what has been called the "[weapon merge glitch](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=214935406)", because other glitches exist with identical methodology to apply the special effects of other weapons to other weapons. I confirm that following these steps with [Bane](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bane) or [Morningstar](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Morningstar) causes effects of these weapons to be applied to other weapons wielded, at least Bane's firing sound effect and Morningstar's weapon-switch sound effect.

Which version of Borderlands 2 am I confirming this on? The bottom-right corner of my Match browser/Online Games menu says, "Version 1.8.3". Otherwise, "Details" tab of the "Properties" of my "Borderlands2.exe" file: "File version  1.0.29.41124", "Product version 1.0.29.827556", and "Date modified  2014-07-15 22:59".

Apparently, it is also possible to "[stack](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638785-borderlands-2/64910943)" the effect at-will so that even weapons that consume greater than one ammo per pull-of-the-trigger may have their ammo cost reduced to 0 as well, but stacking only seems possible before version 1.4.

Update: [ProfessorBroman](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCznXuWp59-geC7F-jaF9_2A) explains the glitch more in-depth [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSyyE09FZfU). He's a Borderlands 2 speed-runner who uses glitches extensively, so I trust his theory. In summary, on the latest patches, the glitch cannot reduce ammo consumption by more than one, and other entities using Vladof rocket launchers can unset the effect.

Update 2: While the AGDQ 2014 co-op speed-run demonstrates this being done as non-host, I was unable to perform this glitch as non-host on patch 1.8.3. And ProfessorBroman stated [such](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSyyE09FZfU#t=4m19).

Comment: I can confirm that this is essentially a way to "merge" weapon effects, and works on all weapons with special effects (such as the Rubi/Grog Nozzle life drain and drunk effect).

Answer (score 0):

its possible that they use an infinity pistol and merge it with it or just use the pistol alone

this pistol is obtained by doc mercy after finishing the mission given by dr. Zed at sanctuary

Answer (score 0):

For this glitch to work, the vladof weapon must be on the round it is gonna make free to fire. The way that has worked every time for me is to try and switch weapons normally without firing the rocket. If it doesnt work, then fire one round and try again. Its possible you may have to attempt this a second time if firing a round and trying again doesn't work.

So to put it into steps:

1. Have your Vladof weapon in your hand
2. Switch weapons with dpad/button and quickly go into inventory
3. Switch around the two weapons you just swapped
4. Try firing weapon to see if it worked.

If that doesn't work, pull your Vladof back out and fire one round and repeat steps 1-4. You shouldn't have to try more than twice.